# JavaScript classes and 'this'

Tags: javascript

```
class Aa {
    methodA() {
        console.log('welcome to method a')
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log('welcome to method b')
        //   methodA() // Fails!! Uncaught ReferenceError: methodA is not defined
        this.methodA() // Works because of this.
    }
}

let myclass = new Aa()
myclass.methodB()
```

What is the best way to **concisely explain** why you need to use 'this' when calling another method of the class that you are already in?

Intuition might say, well if JS knows that I'm using a method of a class, then it knows about that class...because I'm using it's method.....so why can't it find another method of that same class without me telling it...yeah 'this' same place!

By way of contrast, functions can do it with no problem:

```
function a() {
    console.log('welcome to function a')
}
function b() {
    console.log('welcome to function b')
    a() // works without any sort of 'scope help'
}
b()
```

I want to be able to explain it without getting people distracted with needing to know the deepest reasons for it.  If possible, ha!

Part of me just wants to say, "That's how JS classes work.  You gotta 'this'-ify things."

Comment: The easiest way to understand "classes" in js is to first understand that there are no "classes" in js. Its all syntactical sugar for prototypes. So in order to understand why you have to explicitly use "this" in "classes" you need to understand why you need to use "this" in methods on a prototype.

Comment: When using class, you create a kind of template for your object. Each object has its own properties & methods, that means it's has its own context hence that's why to call a class method , you must specify the context `this`. For the function, since you declare its outside class, there is no context (just in a `global context`), then you don't need to use the keyword `this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* confusing mostly because Javascript has a long history of trying to fit the square peg of prototypes into the round hole of classes. A lot of things that make sense in traditional object-oriented languages only lead to confusion in javascript.

Your (very reasonable) intuition goes off the rails here:

> Intuition might say, well if JS knows that I'm using a method of a class, then it knows about that class...because I'm using it's method

`methodA()` and `methodA()` are *just functions*. They don't know anything about where they were defined. What they know is *how they were called.* `this` is the key to tying how the function is called to the rest of the class. Consider this example:

```js
class Aa {
  methodA() {console.log('welcome to method a')}
  methodB() {
    console.log('welcome to method b')  
    this.methodA() // Works because of this.
  }
}

let obj = {
  methodA() { console.log("welcome to imposter A")}
}

let myclass = new Aa()

obj.methodB = myclass.methodB // take a reference to methodB and add it a different obj

console.log("Same?",obj.methodB === myclass.methodB) 
// identical function but it has no idea
// it "belongs" to myclass. Called from a different context
// it acts like a normal function (because it is)
obj.methodB()
```

The function `obj.methodB` doesn't *know* it belongs to `class Aa`. The only thing the relates it to the class is the way it's called and the way it's called determines the value of `this`. So `this` (and the prototype chain) is the glue that holds the whole scheme together.

Answer (score 14):

In order to understand why we need to explicitly reference `this` in Javascript classes, we first need to understand what the `this` reference points to in ordinary functions.

#### This

In Javascript the `this` keyword is always a reference to the object that called the function. 
Consider the following:

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo() { console.log(this); }
}
obj1.foo(); // "this" will reference "obj1"
```

Nothing strange here, `this` is a reference to the object where it was defined `obj1`.

---

Now think about what would happen if we took the function `foo` and "removed" it from the object. Since `this` is a reference to the object that called the function, what should `this` be if the function doesn't belong to an object?

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo() { console.log(this); }
}
const foo = obj1.foo;
foo(); // "this" will reference "window"
```

This is were things start to become strange, `this` is actually a reference to the `global` object. This is because everything in Javascript is an object, even the root level of a file. In the browser this global object is called the `window` object.

---

Now consider what happens if we reattache the method to another object?

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo() { console.log(this); }
}
const foo = obj1.foo;
const obj2 = {};
obj2.foo = foo;
obj2.foo(); // "this" will reference "obj2"
```

The same rules apply here, since the function now belongs to an object again the `this` reference points to `obj2`.

#### Classes

Fist of all Javascript doesn't actually have classes. A js class in just a different way of writing a prototype.

Lets start by writing a simple class.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() { console.log("I'm a Class constructor") }
  log() { console.log("I'm a Class method") }
}

const obj1 = new Foo(); // I'm a Class constructor
obj1.log(); // I'm a Class method
```

Now lets write the same "class" as a prototype.

```js
function Bar() {
  console.log("I'm a Prototype constructor")
}
Bar.prototype = { 
  log() {
    console.log("I'm a Prototype method")
  }
}

const obj2 = new Bar(); // I'm a Prototype constructor
obj2.log(); // I'm a Prototype method
```

These two ways of writing inheritance (classes & prototypes) are the same thing in Javascript.

So as we can more clearly see in the prototype implementation the "class methods" are actually just an object assigned to the prototype of a function.

---

Now that we know about `this` and about `classes / prototypes` we can see that a class method is actually just a function on an object and that `this` refers to the the object that called the function. So if we want to reference another function on the same object we should do so by referencing it through the `this` reference.

```js
class Aa {
    methodA() {
        console.log('welcome to method a')
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log('welcome to method b')
        this.methodA()
    }
}

const myclass = new Aa()
myclass.methodB()
```

Comment: I've never really understood how `this` works in Javascript until I read the 2nd paragraph in your answer: **In Javascript the `this` keyword is always a reference to the object that called the function.** I never thought it was so simple. +1!

Comment: @Daniel That's awesome! Thank you :)