# How do you represent a class as a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Per [Classes in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> Classes are in fact **"special functions"**

How would something like

```
class Foo {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  foo() {}

}
```

be translated to just `function` (ignoring the "hoisting" feature)

Comment: `typeof Foo == "function"`. You're done.

Comment: There are loads of examples of this already, look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51675487/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), (as much as [constructor functions based on *class* syntax are not hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#hoisting),) due to an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which serves as module pattern ...

```
const Foo = (function () {    //  class Foo {
                              //
  function Foo(x) {           //    constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;               //      this.x = x;
  }                           //    }
  function foo() {            //    foo() {
  }                           //
  Foo.prototype.foo = foo;    //    }
                              //
  return Foo;                 //
                              //
}());                         //  }
```

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano ... *ray hatfield* and me most probably earned the downvotes for stepping into the minefield of answering an anyhow not well received question by providing approaches which are far from a full coverage of all the features that come with real JS *class*es.

Comment: Answers the question anyway on how a class is represented as a function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// declare the "class"
function Foo (x) {
  this.x = x;
}

// declare the instance method
Foo.prototype.foo = function () {
  return 'i am foo';
}

// create an instance
const f = new Foo(42);

// invoke its methods
console.log(f.foo()); // 'i am foo'

// access its properties
console.log(f.x); // 42
```

Comment: This is pretty straight forward.  I was torn between this answer and the other one.  The advantage of the other one is it's not `hoisted` which represents a class better.

Comment: Fair enough. Obviously this wasn't intended as a thorough exploration of classes; just a simplest-possible example of how classes shake out to functions.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: To make it non-hoisted the only thing you need to change is `function Foo (x) {` to `const Foo = function (x) {`.

Answer (score -1):

Well really everything is objects - a class is simply a blueprint for an object that has some methods and some values. It's all objects with features that can either store values or transform values.

A class is something - a function does something. Calling it a special function is if anything unnecessary at best and confusing at worst.

Basically - don't worry about it.

Comment: Maybe this is true in other languages, but `typeof class {} === "function"` is pretty fundamental to JavaScript.

Comment: When would you need to define a class as a function? I mean it IS a syntactic sugar for a constructor function but it also technically is an object. Like why would you?